# How do I edit the output of a field?

Tags: 7, views, entities, services

I am creating REST API using Services Module in Drupal 7.

I have created a View to Get lists of Groups. In this views, I have added a Field privacy which will tell if the group is Private or Public.

I am getting this Output if group is Private:

```
privacy":{"value":"1"},
```

and if the group is Public :

```
"privacy":[]
```

How can I edit the output of this field so that it become easier for app developer ? I want to have something like this in output :

```
For Private : privacy":{"value":"1"}, 
For Public  : privacy":{"value":"0"},
```

Or something like this which look good.

Comment: Give this a try: In views click on your privacy field and in **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR** put `0`  if that doesn't work then try putting `{"value":"0"},`

Comment: which module are you using for Field privacy? Is that the [User Field Privacy](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_privacy) module?

Answer (score 0):

From the code you can use [hook_services_request_postprocess_alter()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!docs!services.alter.api.php/function/hook_services_request_postprocess_alter/7) to alter whatever you want from your response.

You can always use arguments to make your changes more specific:

```
function my_module_services_request_postprocess_alter($controller, $args, &$result) {
  // In my response, I include the request string in the '_links' array.    
  // I can use this now to determine which resource was requested.  
  if (strpos($result->_links['self']['href'], 'api/1.0/widget')) {
    // Now I know I'm dealing with a widget request, so I'll
    // add the random string here...
    $result->String = "This is a string that I'm adding to the widget response";
  }
}
```

As result you can see in your response:

```
Array (
  [_links] => Array (
    [self] => Array (
      [href] => /api/1.0/widget/12345
    )
  )

  [count] => 1
  [_embedded] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
      [id] => 12345
      [type] => widget
      [path] => /node/157601
    )
  )
  [String] => 'This is a string that I'm adding to the widget response'
)
```

Read more [Drupal: Alter API response with Services API](http://axlroach.com/post/103200902970/drupal-alter-api-response-with-services-api), where is this example was taken from.